# To hide a label when a particular option is selected in combobox pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a combo box which has multiple options, I would like to display label when a particular option is selected and hide the label when other option is selected. I want to achieve this as soon as the user selects the option in combobox. I tried doing it by using currentindexchanged() but it applies to all the options.

For example, if I select option1 label should be displayed and when i select option 2 the label should be vanished.

Please help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.__ui__()

    def __ui__(self):
        layout_parent = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        data_list = ["option1", "option2", "option3", "option4", "option5", "option6"]
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.addItems(data_list)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.currentIndexChanged)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World!")
        layout_parent.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        layout_parent.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout_parent)

    def currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        if self.comboBox.itemText(index) == "option1":
            self.label.show()
        else:
            self.label.hide()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks..will give it a try.